# GSI Error while trying to use GoogleOAuth

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

Im teaching my self how to use GoogleOAuth and Google-login. Im working in a dummy ReactJs app where i want just to authenticate a login with google but im having the following error message in my console:

```
[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.
```

This is my App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import LoginBtn from './components/atoms/LoginBtn';

function App() {
  return (

    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="myClientID Goes Here">
      <div className="App">
        <LoginBtn />
      </div>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my Login component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';



const LoginBtn = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        
        <GoogleLogin
          onSuccess={credentialResponse => {
            console.log(credentialResponse);
          }}
          onError={() => {
            console.log('Login Failed');
          }}
          useOneTap
        />
        
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginBtn
```

On my credential URI´s i just inserted my localhost URI

```
https://localhost:3000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set both `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:3000` to the authorized Javascript Origin Box in the Credentials page. Find the details [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid#get_your_google_api_client_id)